# Optimization of a value calculated using many variables and constraints

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I'm trying to create a calculator for flexural capacity of reinforced concrete. It is working but the iteration/optimization part is done manually through user input. I'd like it to be automatically calculated/iterated.

The "**x**" value must be **0** by adjusting only the "**c**" and retaining all other input.

Currently, the user inputs a value for "**c**", then the program calculates. When the "**x**" value isn't **0**, then the user would try another value of "**c**", and re-calculate.

The calculation is just based on similar triangles, but with certain constraints, done using the if-else statements (due to material properties).

```
Asb = n*math.pi*math.pow(db,2)/4
Ast = nt*math.pi*math.pow(dbt,2)/4

if comp <= 28:
    beta = 0.85
elif comp >=56:
    beta = 0.65
elif 28 < comp < 56:
    beta = 0.85-.05*(comp-28)/7

c = float(centry.get())

a = beta * c

conca = w * a
conccg = a / 2
botstr = 0.003*(de-c)/c

if c > det:
    topstr = -0.003*(c-det)/c
else:
    topstr = 0.003*(det-c)/c

concstress =-beta*comp
concforce = concstress * conca/1000
concmoment = concforce * conccg/1000

if botstr * 200000>= yld:
    botstress = yld
else:
    botstress = botstr*200000


if abs(topstr) * 200000 >= yld:
    if topstr < 0:
        topstress = -yld
    else:
        topstress = yld
else:
    topstress = topstr*200000


botforce = botstress * Asb/1000
botmoment = botforce * de/1000
topforce = topstress * Ast/1000
topmoment = topforce * det/1000

momcapacity = concmoment+botmoment+topmoment

x = concforce + topforce + botforce
```

I am considering bisection method, but I've got no idea how to apply the code in this case since the calculation involves multiple if-else statements, and most examples I've seen presented only a single equation (ex. y = x^2 +b)

Anyways, if you have better suggestion other than bisection method, I could use it instead.

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: To make a suggestion, consider automatic differentiation packages that both implement derivatives from provided functions (and constraints), and optimizer performance - example: [PyADOL-C](https://github.com/b45ch1/pyadolc). If preferring to code things yourself but performance is important, I'd suggest doing it with C++, as Python can be significantly slower.

Comment: Hello OverLordGoldDragon, I don't mind using packages, will check it out.
Thanks!